# Dataframe missing the time label after assigning clusters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the below data sample

```
date,00:00:00,00:15:00,00:30:00,00:45:00,01:00:00,01:15:00,01:30:00,01:45:00,02:00:00,event
2008-01-01,115.87869701,115.37569504,79.9510802,123.68891355,110.89528693, 112.15190765,110.1277647,76.16662078,100.39338951,A
2008-01-02,104.29757522,89.11652179,91.80890697,109.91423556,112.91809129,114.91459611,117.50170579,111.08030786,81.5893157,B
2008-01-02,81.16506701,97.13170328,89.25478466,93.51884481,107.11447296,120.40638709,116.1653649,79.8861492,111.99530301,C
2008-01-02,121.98507602,105.20973701,84.46996209,96.2210916,107.65437228,121.4604217,120.96638889,117.94695867,94.33309319,D
2008-01-02,82.5839125,104.3308685,98.32658468,101.79562494,86.02883206,90.61788466,109.89027977,107.89093632,101.64082595,E
2008-01-02,100.68446746,89.90700858,115.97450984,112.85364917,100.76204374,87.49141078,81.69930821,79.78106694,99.97354515,F
2008-01-02,98.49917234,112.93161335,85.30015915,120.59233515,102.15602621,84.9536008,116.98786228,107.95753105,112.75693735,G
2008-01-02,76.5186262,111.22137123,102.20065099,88.4490991,84.67584098,86.00205813,95.02734271,114.29076806,102.62969032,H
2008-01-02,93.27785451,122.90242719,123.27263927,102.83454346,87.84973282,95.38098403,88.03719802,108.68335342,97.6581398,I
2008-01-02,119.589143,94.15858259,94.32809506,120.5637488,120.43827996,79.66190052,100.40782173,89.90362719,80.46005726,J
```

I want to assign clusters to the data and have the final output in the below format

**Expected output**

```
time       date    00:00:00    00:15:00    00:30:00    00:45:00    01:00:00    01:15:00    01:30:00    01:45:00    02:00:00  cluster_num
0     2008-01-01   115.878697  115.375695  79.951080   123.688914  110.895287  112.151908  110.127765  76.166621   100.393390          0
1     2008-01-02   97.622322   102.989982  98.326255   105.193686  101.066410  97.876583   105.187030  101.935633  98.115212           1
```

I have tried the below and the current output does not return 'time' label in the first row

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq, whiten
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from sklearn import metrics

#read data
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', index_col=0)
df = df.drop(['event'], axis=1)

#stack the data
df = df.stack()
df.index = pd.to_datetime([' '.join(i) for i in df.index])
df = df.rename_axis('event_timestamp').reset_index(name='value')
df.index = df.event_timestamp
df = df.drop(['event_timestamp'], axis=1)
df.columns = ['value']

#normalize the df
df_norm = (df - df.mean()) / (df.max() - df.min())
df['time'] = df.index.map(lambda t: t.time())
df['date'] = df.index.map(lambda t: t.date())
df_norm['time'] = df_norm.index.map(lambda t: t.time())
df_norm['date'] = df_norm.index.map(lambda t: t.date())

#pivot data
df_daily = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index='date', columns='time', aggfunc='mean')
df_daily_norm = pd.pivot_table(df_norm, values='value', index='date', columns='time', aggfunc='mean')

#assign clusters to daily data
df_daily_matrix_norm = np.matrix(df_daily_norm.dropna())
centers, _ = kmeans(df_daily_matrix_norm, 2)
cluster, _ = vq(df_daily_matrix_norm, centers)
clusterdf = pd.DataFrame(cluster, columns=['cluster_num'])
dailyclusters = pd.concat([df_daily.dropna().reset_index(), clusterdf], axis=1)
print(dailyclusters)
```

**Current output**

```
       date        00:00:00    00:15:00    00:30:00    00:45:00    01:00:00    01:15:00    01:30:00    01:45:00    02:00:00  cluster_num
0     2008-01-01   115.878697  115.375695  79.951080   123.688914  110.895287  112.151908  110.127765  76.166621   100.393390          0
1     2008-01-02   97.622322   102.989982  98.326255   105.193686  101.066410  97.876583   105.187030  101.935633  98.115212           1
```

What do I need to do to get the desired output with the 'time' label.

Answer (score 0):

simply add the name to the index:

```
dailyclusters.index.name = "time"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
dailyclusters = df_daily.dropna().assign(cluster_num=cluster).reset_index()
print(dailyclusters)

# Output
time        date    00:00:00    00:15:00   00:30:00    00:45:00    01:00:00    01:15:00    01:30:00    01:45:00    02:00:00  cluster_num
0     2008-01-01  115.878697  115.375695  79.951080  123.688914  110.895287  112.151908  110.127765   76.166621  100.393390            1
1     2008-01-02   97.622322  102.989982  98.326255  105.193686  101.066410   97.876583  105.187030  101.935633   98.115212            0
```

Comment: Great! What do I need to do to ensure that the time label is not dropped on subsequent manipulations. Please see the edited question